# Symfony 2 - "Internal" bundle routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Is there any way to register bundle's routing from within bundle itself and not importing it in the main routing file?
Now my `routing.yml` looks like this:

```
my_route:
    resource: "@MyExampleAdhocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

However, I would like to somehow enable bundle routing in ExampleBundle class or bundle config, so it will be on only if bundle is registered in AppKernel.

Answer (score 0):

No. For every bundle the routing must be imported in `routing.yml`. Every popular bundle (like FOSUserBundle) have to do this also.

So no bundle can override users routing. Importing the routes in `routing.yml` offers the option to define a prefix or host option on this imported routes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this inside your bundle extension file (AcmeDemoExtension for the AcmeBudle) ?

I think you should look inside `Kernel::buildContainer` to understand how it's done and how you can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I think [custom route loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) is the answer.

> A custom route loader allows you to add routes to an application without including them, for example, in a Yaml file. This comes in handy when you have a bundle but don't want to manually add the routes for the bundle to app/config/routing.yml. This may be especially important when you want to make the bundle reusable, or when you have open-sourced it as this would slow down the installation process and make it error-prone.
>   Alternatively, you could also use a custom route loader when you want your routes to be automatically generated or located based on some convention or pattern.

Comment: Routes from custom route loader must be also [mentioned in `routing.yml`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html#using-the-custom-loader)

Comment: You're right but the bundle is responsible enabling and disabling routes - which solves the problem. :)